# How to redirect current tab's url in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, used to switch between different search engines. The `manifest.json` looks like:

```
{
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
        ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.baidu.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
        }]
}
```

- `content.js` is used to get user's keywords in searching.
- `popup.html` contains a list of supported search engines.

When user clicks on search engine's icon in popup window, I need to redirect current tab to a new url using the search engine user selected.

Now I can get keyword. **Problem is: How to redirect current tab to new url?**

Comment: Which part presents a problem? Have you already done the keyword detection and click handlers in the popup?

Comment: Yes, I can get keyword now. But I don't know how to redirect to new url. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 possible approaches:

A. Let the popup handle redirection.
B. Let the content script handle redirection.

In both cases, you need to solve 2 problems:

1. Communicate information between the two. In approach A, you need to get the keywords from the content script. In approach B, you need to tell the content script which engine to switch to.

   Both are solved using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). I recommend messaging from the popup to the content script using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` (and responding in approach A), because in the other direction content script doesn't know when to send the message (popup may be closed).
2. Actually trigger the change. In approach A, [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) does the trick. In approach B, content script can change `window.location` to navigate away.

Comment: That works great! :-D Though I have a confusion. Why `chrome.tabs.update` only redirect current tab, not all tabs?

Comment: It usually takes a first argument, `tabId`, but when it's not provided it defaults to currently active tab.

Comment: Actually, same with `tabs.sendMessage`: it defaults to active tab.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

See [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update), you could update the url of current tab via the following code

```
chrome.tabs.update({url: "http://www.baidu.com"});
```

Considering you get the keyword from content script, and want to redirect the url after user clicks some button in popup page, you may need [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to share the keywords between content script and popup page.